# jinja2 get whole context in single object within template

Tags: jinja2

For example, I have template **index.html** and **custom_jinja2_filter**

```
    <h1> My name is {{ name }} </h1>
    <h2> I'm {{ year }} years old </h2>
    <p> I'd like to pass template context to custom 
        filter like single object. Is it possible? 
        {{ ??? | custom_jinja2_filter  }} 
    </p>


def custom_jinja2_filter(context):
   name = context['name']
   year = context['year']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the current context to a function marked as callable with [`@contextfunction`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#jinja2.contextfunction):

```
from jinja2 import contextfunction


@contextfunction
def custom_jinja2_filter(context):
    name = context.name
    year = context.year
    return '(c) {} {}'.format(year, name)
```